# Can I use Stripe directly instead of IAP for paying rent?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm working on an app that facilitates communication between landowners and renters. From my research, the most desired feature is to pay directly from the app.

Do I need to use the in-app purchase in this case?

The rent and service payments are strictly real-world; if I understand correctly, they can use things like Stripe.

I think, I apply for "3.1.3" section:

> 3.1.3(e) Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase physical goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry.

Comment: Yes.  Not only can you use an alternative payment method, you must.  You cannot use IAP for your case.